# my website is not indexing in GSC properly lots of pages are not getting indexed

Tags: search, console

my website is not indexing in GSC properly lots of pages are not getting indexed

My website is pillsadviser.com

Please help me out

i tried manual indexing but it showing "
Page cannot be indexed: Not available due to a site-wide issue"